# Limiting Django ModelChoiceField queryset to selected items

Tags: django, django-forms, validation, manytomanyfield

Here is what I've been struggling for a day...

I have a Message model in which `recipients` is a `ManyToManyField` to the `User` model.

Then there is a form for composing messages. As there are thousands of users, it is not convenient to display the options in a multiple select widget in the form, which is the default behavior. Instead, using FcbkComplete jquery plugin, I made the recipients field look like an input field where the user types the recipients, and it WORKS.

But...

Although not visible on the form page, all the user list is rendered into the page in the select field, which is something I don't want for obvious reasons.

I tried overriding the ModelChoiceField's behavior manipulating validation and queryset, I played with the MultipleChoice widget, etc. But none of them worked and felt natural.

So, what is the (best) way to avoid having the whole list of options on the client side, but still be able to validate against a queryset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by overriding the `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`'s default widget. The new widget returns only the selected fields, not the entire list of options:

```
class SelectMultipleUserWidget(forms.SelectMultiple):
    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        choices = [c for c in self.choices if str(c[0]) in selected_choices]
        self.choices = choices
        return super(SelectMultipleUserWidget, 
                     self).render_options([], selected_choices)

class ComposeForm(forms.Form):
    recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                                widget=SelectMultipleUserWidget)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [django-ajax-selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/)? I've never used it, but it's in my mental grab bag for when I come across a problem like what it sounds like you're trying to solve...

Answer (score 1):

I would be trying one of two ways (both of which might be bad! I'm really just thinking out aloud here):

1. Setting the field's queryset to be empty (queryset = Model.objects.none()) and having the jquery tool use ajax views for selecting/searching users. Use a clean_field function to manually validate the users are valid.
2. This would be my preferred choice: edit the template to not loop through the field's queryset - so the html would have 0 options inside the select tags. That is, not using form.as_p() method or anything.

One thing I'm not sure about is whether #2 would still hit the database, pulling out the 5k+ objects, just not displaying them in the html. I don't think it should, but... not sure, at all!

Comment: for 1, clean() is called before the clean_field() and raises an `invalid option` exception. the `clean` should also be overridden, but it is an option. for 2, i don't want to mess with the template because i have site-wide field and form templates. but this is an option too. i still feel there should be a cleaner, less hacky, more djangoish way. thank you.

Comment: The only possible solutions to your problem (assuming queryset filters aren't sufficient) involve having to use javascript and ajax views. In my opinion, thats already hacking a fair bit - you can only expect django to be self consistent, it can't cater for every possibility where javascript is used. And I guess I'd override the clean() method to make it work before calling super() on it :/ mmm hacky indeed!

Comment: Another option is to change the field to a CharField, make the javascript on the page return a comma-separated string of user-ids - no problem with validation/cleaning then, and override save() to do the m2m saving.

Comment: using CharField causes problem with fcbkcomplete, because it expects a select field. i can use something else instead of fcbkcomplete but as i need to display the user's name and post the user id, using a select field seems more natural. i still hope there is a clean and dry way out there :/

Comment: @user608133: removing options from the template does not avoid hitting the database because the form field executes list() on the queryset forcing the query to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about suggestions, and is OK to use the ID, Django Admin comes with a [raw_id_field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) attribute for these situations.

You could also make a widget, that uses the username instead of the ID and returns a valid user. Something among the lines of:

```
# I haven't tested this code. It's just for illustration purposes
class RawUsernameField(forms.CharField):
  def clean(self, value):
    try:
      return User.objects.get(username=value)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      rause forms.ValidationError(u'Invalid Username')
```

Comment: this form is for end users, so raw_id_field would not be appropriate. for the 2nd approach, the custom field should inherit from a ChoiceField because i need to keep both the user id and the name as in a select widget options' key and value pair, for the name is displayed and the id is posted. but with the ChoiceField, there should be a queryset defined during initialization and results in other problems which can be avoided but with hacky ways. thank you.